# Example Powerful Pro-$p$-Groups

Tags: profinite-groups, pro-p-groups

I'm seeking for 
some nice examples for **powerful pro-p-groups*** for prime $p \neq 
2$.

By definition a powerful $p$- group $G$ is definined by following property:
The commutator $[G,G]$ is contained in $ G^p = ⟨ g^p | g ∈ G ⟩ $.

For pro-$p$ case $G$ is endowed with pro-$p$-topology, so we have following modified condition:

$[G,G] \subset \overline{G^p} $.

Comment: I suppose you have seen the thesis of [Smyth](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~danielch/thesis/smyth.pdf)? The title is promising.

Comment: Take a peek here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045824/nontrivial-examples-of-pro-p-groups